# how to get axVLCPlugin21 to play video the size of the axVLCPlugin21 control window?

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am playing a video file that is 1280 x 720 in axVLCPlugin21 like this:

```
var file = @"C:\test\Amex.mov";
var convertedURI = uri.AbsoluteUri;
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(convertedURI);
axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

The video does play just fine but it is at the full size 1280x720 the window is 1/3 that size. My understanding is VLC should just automatically scale the video to the size of the axVLCPlugin21 control window. I am using the latest version of VLC 3.0.4 downloaded just a few days ago. I am using VS2015 and .NET 4.5 (I have tried .NET 4.6 and .NET 4.7 also. The full VLC application plays the video at the size of the window? Is there something I need to set in axVLCPlugin21 to get it to automatically scale the video to the size of the control window?

Comment: My guess is this has something to do with winforms app on a win10 4K laptop - the video actually plays at something like twice it's normal resolution when I drag the application window out to nearly full screen it takes up more than 80% of my 4K laptop screen.

Comment: In other words what I want is fit video to window - is there an option or way to do that with axVLCPlugin21?

Answer (score 0):

> In other words what I want is fit video to window

I had same problem however my project is C++, in order to get that done you need to set video scale to 1 after the `InitializeComponent()` otherwise you get an exception.

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this->axVLCPlugin21->video->scale = 1;
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }
//Rest of the C++ file...
```

I assume that code would look like this in C#:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
    {
    public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.axVLCPlugin21.video.scale = 1;
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }
//Rest of the C# file...
```

You could also wrap all your axVLCPlugin21 components in a method to set all its video scales and call that method after `InitializeComponent()` if you want something more elegant.

Let me know if this solution worked for you, because that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try and post back, but seems like this should work!